# Hibernate pulls up all child records of a parent, not just the constrained children

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I got Cat entity which is parent, CatDts which is one to many child collection.
I want to get all Cat which have CatDt.name='a'. The generated sql query is correct but when accessing the CatDts collection, all child recs are returned and not just those with name 'a'. Any help appreciated, thanks!

**Tables**

```
Cat         CatDt
id          id      name    cat_id
----        ---     ---     ---
1           100     a       1
2           101     a       2
            102     xyz     2
```

So I need just 1-100, 2-101 but it also gives me 2-102

**Cat entity**

```
private List<CatDt> catDts = new ArrayList<CatDt>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cat", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<CatDt> getCatDts() {
    if(this.catDts==null){
        this.catDts = new ArrayList<CatDt>();
    }
    return this.catDts;
}
```

**CatDt entity**

```
private Cat cat;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_ID", nullable = false)
public Cat getCat() {
    return this.cat;
}
```

**Service**

```
public List<Cat>findAllByOption(CatOption options){
    QCat cat = QCat.cat;
    QCatDt catDt = QCatDt.catDt;
    List<Cat> cats = jpaQueryFactory.selectFrom(cat)                
                .innerJoin(catDt).on(cat.id.eq(catDt.cat.id).and(catDt.name.eq("a")))
                .where(cat.status.eq(new BigDecimal(0))).fetch();
    return cats;
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
public void testCatWithOptionsJpaQuery(){
    CatOption options = new CatOption();
    options.setStatus(new BigDecimal(0));
    options.setName("a");
    List<Cat> catList = catService.findAllByOption(options); //-->returns 2 rows
    for(Cat cat:catList){
        logger.info("--" + cat.toString()); //-->gets the child collection catDts and pulls out all rows, not just constrained ones
    }
    Assert.notNull(catList, "categories returned cannot be null!");
}
```

I check logs and find, at below line of Test, sql query & join is good, just returns 2 rows of Cat.

```
catService.findAllByOption(options)
```

But when I iterate those 2 Cat objects, Hibernate pulls out all correspoding CatDt child collection (total 3).
So how do I get just the child records with name='a'?

**Update 1**

When execution reaches below line within the loop in Test, it throws up the individual select statements, that's how the 3 records are being returned instead of 2. I think this is how orm is supposed to work but how to get just constrained children?

```
logger.info("--" + cat.toString())
```

Comment: I think this is Hibernate behavior. So we have to filter at the service/repo level, then again at entity Hibernate level using FilterDef and Filter. Isn't that doing it **twice**? Can we not somehow set child to filtered collection when fetching at service/repo level? If we do that for our 150+ entities then defeats purpose as Hibernate/Spring Data is supposed to use their _'magic'_ abstract these low level stuff for us?

Comment: And if I have to get only those parent (along with multiple child sets say child1, child 2 meeting criteria) matching multiple criteria on parent as well as on different children do i use querydsl/predicates and fetch data from repo? It gets all matching parents, fine but then a call to parent1.getChild1() returls entire set, not just constrained ones. So we need to set Hibernate Filter on each child, then iterate returned parents & fetch all child sets? This sounds definitely wrong. Please advise.

Comment: OK so we can get it done manually by looping all returned parents and then getting related children & setting them.. surely this is not the right way? What I did was in parent service, loop & call child service.findAll(options), then checking for parent id in child id, adding to set, adding set to parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got around the problem by creating a pojo to hold all joined resulting fields I needed.

My service/repo used querydsl to join & filter, returned List of the pojo.

I think Hibernate is great with one table crud, but for complex joins and results we can use custom objects and Querydsl.

Alternatively I could also loop thru parents and use Hibernate's @Filter.